# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Obtengo el siguiente error al momento de registrar el nombre de la ruta en bd, en este caso si guarda la imagen en la carpeta del servidor más no en bd, esto está en Laravel

Código controlador

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{

       $file = $request->file('file');
       $path = public_path().'/uploads/';
       $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

       $file->move($path, $fileName);

       $projectImage = new ProjectImage();
       $projectImage->project_id = $id;
       $projectImage->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
       $projectImage->file_name = $fileName;
       $projectImage->save();
}
```

Y este es la vista

```
    @extends('app')
@section('css')
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/dropzone.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"    >
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Dropzone
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::open(['route'=> 'file.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'files'=>'true', 'id' => 'my-dropzone' , 'class' => 'dropzone']) !!}
                    <div class="dz-message" style="height:100px;">
                        Arrastra las imagenes aquí
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Guardar</button>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

@endsection
@section('scripts')
    {!! Html::script('js/dropzone.js'); !!}
    <script>
        Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            maxFilezise: 10,
            maxFiles: 5,

            init: function() {}
                var submitBtn = document.querySelector("#submit");
                myDropzone = this;

                submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                });
                this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                    alert("Archivo subido");
                });

                this.on("Completo", function(file) {
                    myDropzone.removeFile(file);
                });

                this.on("Proceso exitoso",
                    myDropzone.processQueue.bind(myDropzone)
                );
            }
        };
    </script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 3):

Creería que te falta el `enctype` respectivo al abrir el formulario:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=> 'file.store', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'method' => 'POST', 'files'=>'true', 'id' => 'my-dropzone' , 'class' => 'dropzone']) !!}
```

Comment: Aún agregándolo, marca el mismo error